# Using default ASP.NET Identity entities with generic repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In previous topic, I successed to merge the default ASP.NET Identity and my own tables context. Next ASP.NET Identity issue, that my generic repository which is working with my tables POCOs, doesn't working with inherited POCOs, like the default ApplicationUser : IdentityUser

How could it be to use the default ASP.Net Identity entities with generic repository?

Here it is my generic repositories main part:

```
public class RepositoryBase<TContext, TEntity> : IRepositoryBaseAsync<TEntity>, IDisposable
    where TContext : IdentityDbContext<MyContext.ApplicationUser>
    where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly TContext _context;
    private readonly IObjectSet<TEntity> _objectSet;

    protected TContext Context
    {
        get { return _context; }
    }

    public RepositoryBase(TContext context)
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            _context = context;
            _objectSet = (_context as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Context cannot be null");
        }
    }
}
```

Of course there are Add, Query etc... methods in the repository, but those are unnecessary in this question.